# PHP POST data empty

Tags: php, html

I'm working on a Google Compute Engine virtual instance to create a simple PHP application, I started testing the PHP environment and it seems the POST is not working properly because it is always empty

When I try `var_dump` and `print_r`, it returns null. I have also tried with `$_REQUEST` and is also empty.

What could be wrong?

Here is the form I'm using

```
<form id="main-contact-form" class="contact-form" action="test.php" method="POST">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Nombre" name="name-contact">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Email" name="email">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            <textarea name="message" id="message" required="required" class="form-control" rows="8" placeholder="Mensaje" name="message"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg">Enviar Mensaje</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and in the `test.php` I try something like

```
echo($_POST['name-contact']);
```

but the error log says that the 'name-contact' index is missing

Comment: Did you remember to close the form? (</form>). Also, what does your full sendemail.php file look like?

Comment: not enough code to support the question to top it off with what seems to be sending mail.

Comment: What does `var_dump($_POST)` return? It looks like you've only tried it for `name-contact`. Have you tried it for the entire global var?

Comment: It's working correctly in my machine! **also note that these two files should be in the same directory** `:)`

Comment: as I said, it is just test code, so in the sendemail.php I just have the echo to test if the POST works properly

Comment: HTML source reveals what exactly?

Comment: @CarlosSchuldiner, I forgot to mention that in my PC I added those `php` tags as Jonas answer suggest! `:)`

Comment: What does `<?php print_r(get_defined_vars());` show ?

Comment: Please post a screenshot of the request and response headers. I could imagine the server is dropping the post variables (WAF style) OR there is kinda redirect somewhere.

Comment: the print_r(get_defined_vars() returns nothing as well.

how can I post a screenshot?